# Puppet Run on hostgroup in UI results in: Failed to apply catalog: Broken pipe - <STDOUT>

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

When attempting a "run puppet" from the UI (1.11.0 - thanks for the improved UI speed, btw) on a hostgroup (same config/installs/OS, etc), the result will be a "Failed to apply catalog: Broken pipe - " error.  All hosts are Ubuntu Trusty.  Here's a syslog output from a UI Puppet Run on 20 nodes:

```
Apr 14 11:34:27 pn02 puppet-agent[45865]: Retrieving pluginfacts
Apr 14 11:34:27 pn02 puppet-agent[45865]: Retrieving plugin
Apr 14 11:34:28 pn02 puppet-agent[45865]: Loading facts
Apr 14 11:35:15 pn02 puppet-agent[45865]: Caching catalog for pn02.blahblah.org
Apr 14 11:35:22 pn02 puppet-agent[45865]: Failed to apply catalog: Broken pipe - <STDOUT>
```

However, when running puppet manually from the node, or when the regularly scheduled puppet run executes, the run will complete successfully.  Additionally, individual Puppet Runs, as well as runs on, e.g. 5 nodes from the UI also succeed - it's just the attempt to execute on 20 nodes that produces errors.

Any thoughts on next steps to diagnose?  Is this network-congestion related?  Should my master's hardware be boosted?

Comment: Was "Run puppet" working in earlier versions of Foreman?

Comment: It works just fine if I run it on smaller groups of nodes, just not when I try to run it on e.g. 20.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue!
I was using puppetssh method to run the `puppet agent -t` command.

The error would only show up when running on many hosts.

I was able to fix this by redirecting the STDOUT to /dev/null. I changed my
 'puppetssh_command:' to `sudo puppet agent -t &>>/dev/null`.

Comment: Hmmm...  unless I'm missing something, that didn't work for me :(  I was really hoping you'd got it, too.  Here's what my puppet.yml file looks like now: http://pastebin.com/ByX8Eyw0

Comment: I uploaded my config as well: http://pastebin.com/zj59Nr8g
I had to remove /usr/bin/puppet but i forget why. My default puppet is /bin/puppet.

Do you have puppet_wait: set?

Comment: Also, did you remember to restart the foreman-proxy service?

Comment: I'm assuming that puppet_wait defaults to false?  What you see up there is the entirety of my config file.  I had neglected to restart the service, but I have now, & am still experiencing the same behavior :(